# Is there a way to catch a specific attribute with argument using PHPStan?

Tags: php, phpstan, php-attributes

I want to detect if someone accidentally writes a test attribute like `#[Group('temp')]` using PHPStan. I am also using the https://github.com/ekino/phpstan-banned-code package to catch other debugging statements, but it seems that it doesn't support attributes.